# How to check if a date is in an array of dates in PHP

Tags: php

Most probably a silly question, but after a long day I can to the life of me figure out why this IF is not working. The only thing I can think of fits due to formatting or something

```
$dates = array(
    date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-30 days')), // 30 days ag
    date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-60 days')), // 60 days ago
    date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-90 days')), // 90 days ago
    date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-120 days')), // 120 days ago
);
        
print_r($dates);
        
$post_date = '2021-01-11'; // 30 days ago from today as an example

if (in_array($post_date, $dates)){
 echo $post_date . " is in array";
}
```

Post date is retrieved using Wordpress `get_the_date('Y-m-d') function`, when I echo out `$post_date` i get 2021-01-11

Comment: You format the dates `'Y-m-d'` and then look for a date in the format `2021/01/11`?

Comment: Y-m-d vs. Y/m/d

Comment: Isn't that correct for the 11th January 2021?

Comment: They are stored as strings in the array.

Comment: If I was to actually use the code from the project then I would have messed the post date up in my question. Post date is actually retrieved like this... $post_date = get_the_date("Y-m-d"); so is actually in correct format.

Comment: Then I suggest you update the question (preferably with a `var_dump($post_date);`) to confirm...

Comment: @Steven I've updated the post, var_dump doesn't give me much information as its a string, when I echo out $post_date I get 2021-01-11

Comment: @StuartMoir What is the result of `print_r($dates);`?

Comment: @nice_dev ```Array
(
    [0] => 2021-01-11
    [1] => 2020-12-12
    [2] => 2020-11-12
    [3] => 2020-10-13
)```

Comment: Well if the data you've provided here is correct then your code will work... It sounds like `get_the_date` isn't providing quite the right format, possibly a space where it shouldn't be? Can you try replacing `$post_date` with the appropriate text string of the date: make sure there are no extra characters. Try to `var_dump($post_date, $dates[0]);` They should both return exactly the same `string(10) ...` if there's any difference (e.g. `string(11) ...` then it means you have extra characters You can also try `echo strcmp($post_date, $dates[0])` which should return `0` if the strings are equal

Answer (score 1):

Currently, it is not working because the date format is different in `$dates` and `$post_date`

Try to make both same as below

```
$post_date = '2021-01-11';
```

So it will work as can be seen in below result dump.

[image]

Comment: If I was to actually use the code from the project then I would have messed the post date up in my question. Post date is actually retrieved like this... $post_date = get_the_date("Y-m-d"); so is actually in correct format.

Comment: What is the actual output of $post_date ? try to dump that value and then can further guide

Comment: When I echo out $post_date I get 2021-01-11

Comment: I have updated my answer with screenshot of result. It is working with 2021-01-11